# WCF call with Param List<T> fails when passing a List<MyType>

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

**WCF Service INTERFACE**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    int TestCall(GenericType<MyType> x);

    [OperationContract]
    int TestAnotherCall(GenericType<MyOtherType> x);

}

[DataContract(Name = "GenericType")]
[KnownType(typeof(List<MyType>))]
[KnownType(typeof(List<MyOtherType>))]
public class GenericType<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

**WCF Service IMPLEMENTATION**:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Test : ITest
{
    public int TestCall(GenericType<MyType> x)
    {
        return x.Data.Count; 
    }

    public int TestAnotherCall(GenericType<MyOtherType> x)
    {
        return x.Data.Count; 
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
List<MyType> list = from a in ctx.Table
                    select new MyType (a.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3).ToList(); 

GenericType gt = new GenericType();
gt.Data = list;

using(WCFClient client = new WCFClient())
{
   client.TestCall(gt);
   client.Close();
}
```

**ERROR:**
**The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.**

if I pass NULL to "gt.Data" ...it works fine.

**NOTE:**

> When I put the mouse over the gt.Data ...the hint shows as MyType[]
>   Not sure if that's expected.
>
> After some review, I noticed that the Client Service only knows about
>   the 1st [KnownType] stated, in my case the List. 
>   No knowledge of List ....
>   Is that expected when you put various [KnownType] on the WCF Interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decorate your generic with the [`KnownType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) attribute

```
[DataContract(Name = "GenericType")]
[KnownType(typeof(MyType))]
public class GenericType<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

Quick Working Example:

**Service**

```
[OperationContract]
GenericType<MyType> GetDataUsingDataContract(GenericType<MyType> composite);

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public GenericType<MyType> GetDataUsingDataContract(GenericType<MyType> composite)
    {
        composite.Data.First().Stuff = "Test";
        return composite;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
[DataContract(Name = "GenericType")]
[KnownType(typeof (MyType))]
public class GenericType<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyType
{
    public string Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

**Client**

```
var client = new Service1Client();

var genericType = new GenericType
                        {
                            Data = new[]
                                        {
                                            new MyType(),
                                        }
                        };
var result = client.GetDataUsingDataContract(genericType);
client.Close();

Console.WriteLine(result.Data.First().Stuff);

Console.ReadLine();
```

*this example was generated with adding a service reference and not using a shared assembly*

Comment: Does this mean that if I have 10 different types to use thru the GenericType from the client ...i will have to declare it 10 different Server classes each one with a KnownType(typeof(XXX)) ?

Comment: Just confirming, where is "GetKnownType" coming from ?

Comment: Well, the example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) in wrong copied...

Comment: Fixed the typo. Yes you would need to list each type for the KnownType. This allows for deserialization to work properly.

Comment: 2 "typeof" one after the other ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attribute GenericType with the [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute for each of the classes that it can contain.

For example:

```
[KnownType(typeof(List<MyType>)]
public class GenericType<T>
```

Comment: @Developer: Sorry, was trying to convert my vb syntax to c# and find the MSDN documentation link. Updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer to show the location (just above generictype class)

Comment: Applied that change...still same problem

Comment: Can you try just [KnownType(typeof(MyType)]?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you're not providing a type for `T` in `GenericType` when you instantiate it.  Try this:

```
GenericType<MyType> gt = new GenericType<MyType>();
```

Instead of

```
GenericType gt = new GenericType();
```

It's the same syntax as when you instantiate any other generic class.  For example, to declare a list of strings, (List as in `List<T>`...see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)) you'd say:

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String>();
```

Comment: I tried and i get a compiling error: The non-generic type 'MyNamespace.GenericType' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @Developer - Ok, now you've got me confused. Are you saying that your example code is disingenuous?

Comment: ?? I'm saying that if I apply the suggested change, I get that following error.